# Using two arguments in a panels page?

Tags: panels, organic-groups, views, chaos-tool-suite

Here's what I want to do, for context:

I want to go to `mysite.com/groups/%gid/%nid` and see the node specified by `%nid` with an OG menu and a header pane that get their context based on the %gid. So if I have, say, a "person" nodetype, I can show a person node that belongs to multiple groups with the header and menu of different groups based on the URL. This is useful because then I can change the links that I use in each group's "people" list to keep the header and menu the same after the user clicks on the person.

I am not able to get the two arguments to work together, though.

I have been able to create a Views pane that displays the node by taking nid as a contextual filter, and gets it from the URL via panels. However, when I try to add the `%gid` first, I get all lost. I can't figure out how to use it to tell OG Menu which menu I want, I don't know how to use it to pass the appropriate context to the header minipanel that I've created (that works when a valid context is passed in), and I get "page not found" instead of a person node.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get two arguments in a URL to work together to tell Panels what the context and content should be, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this:

```
  $page->arguments = array(
    // Array key must be unique.
    'node' => array(
      'id' => 1,
      'identifier' => 'Node: ID',
      'name' => 'entity_id:node',
      'settings' => array(),
    ),
  );
```

I found workoroud for this problem. Create custom load hook that will be the similar to node or some else you need. Like this:

```
/**
 * Duplicates node load callback because panels can't have two same entities arguments.
 */
function mymodule_custom_load($nid) {
  return node_load($nid);
}
```

So to solve tis, you need to use %mymodule_custom instead of %node.
Hope this will help somebody, because I search the answer for very long time.